# Getting `ownerAccountId`

Tags: tapkey

I'm using this endpoint `/api/v1/Owners/{ownerAccountId}/BoundLocks` to get boundlocks belonging to a certain account that earlier granted access to my application.
The issue is, every account has a different `ownerAccountId`, how can I get the one associated with a particular lock system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to archive is:

You are using the oAuth2 authenticate code flow. So users grant your services access to their tapkey owner account (locking system).

If this not the correct assumption, the answer might not be correct. Please then update your question with more details and we will provider a matching answer.

You can get all owner accounts of such a user with the `GET /api/v1/Owners` endpoint.
For more informations about this endpoint visit https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_management_api_v1/#/Owners

In general all public available endpoints are listed and described in details here:
https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_management_api_v1/